# Django ModelForm add foreign key after post submit ignored

Tags: python, django

I am currently working on our user profile. A user can add multiple E-Mail addresses to his/her account.

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def profile_update_emails(request):
    context = {}
    ...
    try:
        email = CustomerEmails.objects.get(customer=request.user)
        update_emails_form = UpdateEmailsForm(request.POST or None, instance=email)
    except CustomerEmails.DoesNotExist:
        update_emails_form = UpdateEmailsForm(request.POST or None)
    context.update({'update_emails_form': update_emails_form})

    if request.POST:
        if update_emails_form.is_valid():
            update_emails_form.save(commit=False)
            update_emails_form.customer = request.user
            update_emails_form.save()
            messages.success(request, "All good")

return render(request, 'usercp/profile.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class UpdateEmailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(forms.ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for f in self.fields:
            self.fields[f].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

    class Meta:
        model = CustomerEmails
        fields = ('email',)
```

models.py

```
class CustomerEmails(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

error/trace:

```
IntegrityError at /usercp/profile/profile_update_emails
(1048, "Column 'customer_id' cannot be null")
```

Please note I have a custom user model. Which is not the problem here.

I am not quite sure, why the customer field is not getting populated before the second save() though. There are currently no rows in that table for the CustomerEmails model. (I know that this will clash with the .get() in the future, since a user can have multiple e-mails, but first things first)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the relationship on the model instance, which is returned from the form save, not on the form itself.

```
    obj = update_emails_form.save(commit=False)
    obj.customer = request.user
    obj.save()
```

Comment: Oh Boy. Fridays.. Thank you very much. I went crazy over here, why this is not working....All good thanks Daniel